# Is $R$ an equivalence relation or not?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $\Bbb N := \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and a relation is defined in $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ as follows. $(a, b)$ is related to $(c, d)$ if and only if $ad=bc$ then show whether $R$ is an equivalence relation or not.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: In case you’re stuck on where to start, it always helps to start with definitions. What properties must a relation have to be an equivalence relation? Can you prove that those properties hold for all members of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: **Reflexive:** $(a,b)$ is related to $(a,b)$, since $ab=ab$. **Symmetric:** $(a,b)$ related to $(c,d)$ means $ad=cb$, which is also equivalent to $(c,d)$ being related to $(a,c)$. **Transitive:** If $(a,b)$ is related to $(c,d)$ and $(c,d)$ is related to $(e,f)$, then we have both $ad=cb$ and $cf=ed$. Multiplying these two equations we get $adcf=cbed$, from where $af=eb$. This gives that $(a,b)$ related to $(e,f)$.

Comment: What exactly is $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(a,b)R(c,d)\iff ad=bc$

reflexivity:
$(a,b)R(a,b)$
proof:
$ab=ba$

symmetry:

$(a,b)R(c,d)\iff (c,d)R(a,b)$

here:
$ad=bc = cb=ad$.

transitivity:
$(a,b)R((c,d)\land(c,d)R(e,f)\implies (a,b)R(e,f)$

$ad=bc \land cf=de\implies acf/e=bc\implies af=be$

$a,b,c,d,e,f\in N$ so none is 0.

$\square$